# loop through list of lists in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have playbook to list log files which are older than 30 days.

```yaml
tasks:
  - name : list files older than 30 days
    find:
      paths: /var/log
      patterns: '*.log'
      age: 30d
      file_type: file
      recurse: yes
      age_stamp: mtime
    register: log_output
```

With this task, I get the variable `log_output` as below, which I have masked with boxes due to confidential info.

[image]

I am trying to get the value of `path` key. I was not sure how to get that. I tried using

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{item.files}}"
  with_items: "{{log_output.results}}"
```

Even accessing `item.files` is throwing error. I am not sure how to get the value of the `path` keys.

Comment: There is something you are not showing us here. You will get a `results.*` output from a module only if you do have a `loop` on the tasks that register, which is not the case here. Could you please explain this with a [mre]?

Comment: Also please do not use images for things that are code and can be copy/pasted in the question itself, see [ask]. Image should be limited to visual / graphic things that are more obvious than represented in words.

Comment: Sure next time onwards will take care...

Comment: The same playbook if I use on local VMS as target machines running on my laptop, I don't see results.* in output but when I run in office environment I am seeing some strange behaviour. If in case of above output is unavoidable, how can I get path keyword value

Comment: Sure you don't have a `loop` or `with_*` of any kind on the `find` module having the `register: log_output`? As said, you won't get a `results.*` without a loop of some kind. See: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#results

Comment: It's my mistake. I was referring playbook in backup directory, while checking playbook.

Answer (score 2):

Since your most likely have a `loop` or `with_*` usage in your task registering the files, [you will have a `results` key in your registered variable dictionary](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html#results).

You can use the filters [`map`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.map) and [`flatten`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables) if your goal is to create a single level list out of all the file path.

```yaml
- debug:
    var: log_output.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten | map(attribute='path')
```

Or, if you want to loop on them:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ item.path }}"
  loop: "{{ files.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten }}"
  loop_control:
    label: "{{ item.path }}"
```

---

Given the example playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: "{{ item }}"
      register: files
      loop:
        - /lib
        - /proc
    
    - debug:
        var: files.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten | map(attribute='path')
```

This will give something like:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [find] *******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=/lib)
ok: [localhost] => (item=/proc)

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  files.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten | map(attribute='path'):
  - /lib/libapk.so.3.12.0
  - /lib/libz.so.1.2.11
  - /lib/libssl.so.1.1
  - /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1
  - /lib/libcrypto.so.1.1
  - /proc/fb
  - /proc/dma
  - /proc/kmsg
  - /proc/misc
  - /proc/mtrr
  - /proc/stat
  - /proc/iomem
  - /proc/locks
  - /proc/swaps
  - /proc/crypto
  - /proc/uptime
  - /proc/vmstat
  - /proc/cgroups
  - /proc/cmdline
  - /proc/cpuinfo
  - /proc/devices
  - /proc/ioports
  - /proc/loadavg
  - /proc/meminfo
  - /proc/modules
  - /proc/version
  - /proc/consoles
  - /proc/kallsyms
  - /proc/slabinfo
  - /proc/softirqs
  - /proc/zoneinfo
  - /proc/buddyinfo
  - /proc/config.gz
  - /proc/diskstats
  - /proc/key-users
  - /proc/interrupts
  - /proc/kpagecount
  - /proc/kpageflags
  - /proc/partitions
  - /proc/execdomains
  - /proc/filesystems
  - /proc/kpagecgroup
  - /proc/vmallocinfo
  - /proc/pagetypeinfo
  - /proc/sysrq-trigger

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: but when I use `- debug:
        var: files.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten | map(attribute='path')` , I am not seeing files present in the directory instead of that the following output observed ** "files.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten | map(attribute='path')": "<generator object do_map at 0x6ffffe40f4d0>"**

Comment: `var: files.results | map(attribute='files') | flatten | map(attribute='path') | list` when you end up with a `generator`.